# Hide Module/Package from Trace

Tags: prolog, trace, swi-prolog

How do I hide a module or a whole package from tracing.
I have this query, and I want to step through it, but
I am not interested in what CLP(X) does, only at what point something fails in my query.

```
?- X in 0..5, X in 7..8.
fail.

?- dif(A, 1), A = 1.
fail.
```

If I run this query in SWI-Prolog it shows me every nifty 
detail of the module CLP(X), not only some inlining 
related to the constraints but also everything else from CLP(X):

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.2)

?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- X in 0..5, X in 7..8.
   Call: (9) clpfd:clpfd_in(_2662, 0..5) ? creep
   Call: (10) clpfd:fd_variable(_2662) ? creep
   Call: (11) var(_2662) ? creep
   Exit: (11) var(_2662) ? creep
   Call: (11) true ? creep
   Exit: (11) true ? creep

[trace]  ?- dif(A, 1), A=1.
   Call: (9) dif:dif(_3044, 1) ? creep
   Exit: (9) dif:dif(_3410{dif = ...}, 1) ? creep
   Call: (9) _3410{dif = ...}=1 ? creep
```

Is there a way to suppress the internals of CLP(X). For
example if I use another Prolog system, I don't see any
internals of the CLP(X) (Preview):

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Development Environment 1.3.6

?- trace.
Yes

?- X in 0..5, X in 7..8.
    0 Call X in 0..5 ? 
    0 Exit X in 0..5 ? 
    0 Call X in 7..8 ? 
    0 Fail X in 7..8 ? 
No

?- neq(A, 1), A = 1.
    0 Call neq(A, 1) ? 
    0 Exit neq(A, 1) ? 
    0 Call A = 1 ? 
    0 Fail A = 1 ? 
No
```

Is there an elegant way to disable a module/package, but nevertheless see top-level calls/exits from the module/packge?

Comment: Tracing clpfd leads to nowhere, consider instead to produce generalizations and specialization!

Comment: Most of the time it will show that labeling fails.

Comment: I often would like to use `trace.` and hide just clpfd. It's not like all the work is happening in clpfd. It looks like the recommended thing is to not use `trace.` and instead use `trace(mypred/2, +all).`

Comment: SICStus has the directive `module/3` with a third parameter `[hidden(true)]` for such purpose

Comment: @false take note of the [tag:swi-prolog] tag there.

Comment: @DanielLyons: ???

Answer (score -1):

There are various ways to control the debugging process in SWI-Prolog, see http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugging. In this can you can use the `skip` option, which will "skip to exit port of this call or wake port". The option is activated by pressing <kbd>s</kbd> during the trace intead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

In this case skipping over all calls results in a trace which is very similar to your Jekejeke example (although a bit less nicely formatted):

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- X in 0..5, X in 7..8.
   Call: (9) clpfd:clpfd_in(_7788, 0..5) ? skip
   Exit: (9) clpfd:clpfd_in(_8226{clpfd = ...}, 0..5) ? creep
   Call: (9) integer(_8226{clpfd = ...}) ? skip
   Fail: (9) integer(_8226{clpfd = ...}) ? creep
   Call: (9) clpfd:clpfd_in(_8226{clpfd = ...}, 7..8) ? skip
   Fail: (9) clpfd:clpfd_in(_8226{clpfd = ...}, 7..8) ? creep
false.
```